# Active menu link depending on selected tab

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have a tabbed content on "about us" page which looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="vc_tta-tabs-list">
        <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab="">
            <a href="#tab-1" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab="">
            <a href="#tab-2" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">Tab 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab="">
            <a href="#tab-3" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">Tab 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>


    <div class="vc_tta-panels">
        <div class="vc_tta-panel" id="tab-1" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
            <h1>Tab 1 Content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="vc_tta-panel" id="tab-2" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
            <h1>Tab 2 Content</h1>
        </div>  
        <div class="vc_tta-panel" id="tab-3" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
            <h1>Tab 3 Content</h1>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

In the header of the site i have a menu which links directly to anchors like this

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="about-html#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to figure out a way how to add a "active" class to menu link once a corresponding tab is selected (aka, if user clicks on #tab-2, that link gets "active" class. If he clicks on #tab-3, that class is removed from previous link and applied to new one...

I am a jQuery newbie so i apologize if the question is stupid.
Any help would be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(window).on('load', () => {
  $('.vc_tta-tabs-list').on('click tap', 'a[href*="tab"]', e => {
    $('header a').removeClass('active');
    let href = $(e.target).closest('a').attr('href');
    $("header a[href*='"+href+"']").addClass('active');
  })
})
```

Places `active` class on any `<a>` element contained in `<header>` element, when an `<a>` inside `.vc_tta-tabs-list` is clicked, if the tab link's `href` is contained in the header link's `href`.
Prior to this, it also removes `active` class from all header links that have it.
It only works if the clicked link contains the string *"tab"* inside its `href`. You can remove this limitation by replacing `'a[href*="tab"]'` with `'a'`, on 2nd line.

```js
$(window).on('load', () => {
  $('.vc_tta-tabs-list').on('click tap', 'a[href*="tab"]', e => {
    $('header a').removeClass('active');
    let href = $(e.target).closest('a').attr('href');
    $("header a[href*='"+href+"']").addClass('active');
  })
})
```

```css
header ul {
  display: flex;
}
header li {
  display: block;
  padding-right: 1rem
}
header li .active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="vc_tta-tabs-list">
    <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab="">
      <a href="#tab-1" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab="">
      <a href="#tab-2" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab="">
      <a href="#tab-3" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>


  <div class="vc_tta-panels">
    <div class="vc_tta-panel" id="tab-1" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
      <h1>Tab 1 Content</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="vc_tta-panel" id="tab-2" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
      <h1>Tab 2 Content</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="vc_tta-panel" id="tab-3" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
      <h1>Tab 3 Content</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Andrei, thanks a lot for your help!
When i wrote the code above, i tried to shorten it so it is easier to read, but i messed up because ID's and URL's are little bit different. If i am not asking too much, can you take a look at this snippet https://jsfiddle.net/La3d94zo/3/

Comment: I won't be in front of a computer sooner than 1hr. I can read the code, but can't run it on mobile. Why?

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention: I added the class "menu" to your menu, because targeting all `ul`s in a project seemed way too general. Either add it to your menu or replace `.menu` in the code with `ul` or a more specific selector which applies in your project. Apologies for not mentioning it. I did mean to but I was doing more than one thing at once.

Comment: most likely because i used a absolute URLs... if you can take a look when you are at computer it would mean a lot :)

Comment: You're correct, the above won't work with absolute urls. I took the urls literally. I'll modify it when I get home.

Comment: The problem with your fiddle was a setting to run the JavaScript on the `onload` event. Whenever you use `onload` to bind something to the `onload`, that something is never run. However, I have left the `on('load')` wrapper, because you don't want this code ran when it is met in code. You want it run after page was loaded. I also changed it to be independent of domain.

Comment: this works great, thanks a lot! But this only works if the user clicks on tabs (and the menu item gets "active" class"). Is it possible to do the same thing on menu (if the user clicks on a link in the menu which opens tab - that link gets active class)? I understand that i am asking too much so if you cant help, that is fine.

Comment: this works like a charm! only problem is that with e.preventDefault(); links in main menu dont open the anchor links/tabs. if i remove the preventDefault, then they dont get a active class :D

Comment: here is what i mean, click thru few tabs - it works, menu gets active color. click on menu link, it opens the anchor but the active class isnt on the right menu item - https://jsfiddle.net/La3d94zo/28/